# Using dirset with Ant + Jacoco

Tags: java, ant, jacoco

I'm trying to use jacoco to perform unit tests on files but it keeps popping with `NoClassDefFoundError` and keeps giving new class names every time I sort the previous error out. Till now I've been manually providing the `pathelement location` to the `bin` folders which contain the required `.class` files.

I'd like to fasten the process by using dirset if possible. I've compiled a dirset which contains the bin folders of all the main folders that are required.

**Questions**:

**1**. How do I include this dirset in the classpath such that jacoco looks for the `.class` files in these set of `bin` directories?

**2**. Is there any way in which I can echo the dirset to the cmd to check its contents?

**3**. Why does this not work?

```
<echo message="Build path is: ${toString:ALL.dirs}"/>
```

dirset:

```
<path id="ALL.dirs">
    <dirset dir="${classes.dir}">
        <include name="projects-framework/**/bin"/>
    </dirset>
</path>
```

jacoco code coverage:
Code I've written till now. The "**" in the code are the full locations to the bin folders which I do not think is relevant here.

```
<target name="cov-test">
    <mkdir dir="${report.dir}"/>    
    <jacoco:coverage>
        <junit fork="true" forkmode="once" showoutput="true" printsummary="on" enabletestlistenerevents="true">
            <test name="full.qualified.name.ABC"/>
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
                <path refid="application"/>
                <pathelement location="projects-framework/**/bin"/>
                <pathelement location="projects-framework/**/bin"/>
                <pathelement location="projects-framework/**/bin"/>
                <pathelement location="projects-framework/**/bin"/>
            </classpath>
            <formatter type="plain"/>
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
        </junit>
    </jacoco:coverage>
</target>
```